# Fastest Perl Template Library

Tags: perl

Whats the fastest perl template library that allows me to do the following:

- variable substitution,
- loops (Hashes & Arrays),
- layout (wrapper templates)
- and at least some conditional logic (< > != == %).

..also has anybody used [pltenjin?](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/tenjin/pltenjin-users-guide.html) the benchmarks suggest this is pretty rapid.

Comment: My "response" would be: "Is X too slow"? I would pick the library/web-stack that enabled me to be the most productive and approach the problem as *I* want to approach it -- e.g. where is logic vs. view separation, how much should the template do, is there any special case the engine should cater to, etc.

Comment: @pst. Thanks for your input. It helped me go back and edit the question to try and be more specific.

Comment: [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org)

Comment: @dalton: fastest is still probably not a sensible metric. The bottleneck in web apps is almost never the speed of the templating engine.

Comment: http://illusori.co.uk/projects/Template-Roundup/

Comment: @Philip I was interested in knowing the answer, I never said the template engine would be a bottle neck.

Comment: @dalton: it's perhaps better to explicitly state when you are asking academic questions so that answerers like me don't apply real-world assumptions and constraints to it then :)

Comment: Hi Dalton, I would go for Template::Toolkit, it's performance wise not the fastest, but you easy in development effort more than makes up for that. Used HTML::Template quite a bit, for basic things it is good and fast but can give you troubles if you try to do more than the basics

Comment: @Rob - thanks. I use template toolkit @work but just wondered what the fastest was. Just tinkering at home. I've been playing with HTML::Template::Pro which seems nice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend you the Xslate template engine ([http://xslate.org/](http://xslate.org)), and it's about 50-100 times faster than others. Please, see this comparative benchmarks: http://xslate.org/benchmark.html

The engine enables the use of Template Toolkit (another template engine) compatible template tokens ('[%', '%]'), and you can use commands like: INCLUDE, FOREACH, WHILE, ...

Answer (score 3):

No, I didn't use plTenjin. From my experience, 
this looks almost like HTML::Mason minus the 
nice block syntax of Mason.

What site do you manage which is able to saturate
any modern CPU during template processing? I don't
think this would happen easily.

In most cases, there are different bottlenecks
to site performance than any cpu-bound template
processing.

(BTW, from what I read in the plTenjin doc,
you should give [HTML::Mason](http://www.masonhq.com/) a try..)

Regards

rbo